# Delete a map<int,list<struct*>>

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, memory, memory-management

Guys I am having a problem implementing the destructor of my class that has a `map<int,list<Arestas*>>.`

Using this map as a sample: [image: graph]

My map will look like this:

```
key   list  
[1] - [2,10] -> [3,100] -> [4,25]  
[2] - [1,10] -> [3,50]  
[3] - [2,50] -> [1,100] -> [4,40]  
[4] - [1,25] -> [3,40]
```

My Arestas class contains:

```
class Arestas {
private:
    Fronteira *vertice;
    unsigned int custo;
}
```

My destructor right now looks like this:

```
for (auto it = myGrafo.begin(); it != myGrafo.end(); ++it) {
    for (auto it1 = (*it).second.begin(); it1 != (*it).second.end(); ++it1) {
        delete *it1;
    }
    (*it).second.clear();
}
```

But is giving me this Error when I go for the list from key[2]:

```
_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
I insert in my map the `Arestas*` like this:

```
Arestas *aux = new Arestas();
        aux->setCusto(_custo);
        aux->setVertice(encontrarFronteira(vertice_destino));
        // Se o vertice nao existir
        if (aux->getVertice()->getVertice() == NULL) {
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        myGrafo[vertice_origem].push_back(aux);

        // Put the same path in the opposite vertice
        Arestas *aux1 = new Arestas();
        // set cost
        aux1->setCusto(_custo);
        // it looks for the vertice in the list<vertices*>
        aux1->setVertice(encontrarFronteira(vertice_origem));
        myGrafo[vertice_destino].push_back(aux1);
```

Comment: More data required. Something bad is happening, but it probably happened long ago and the program is really only realizing it during the destructor. For example, a [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation resulting in a double delete. Question: Do you have a strong reason for storing `Arestas*` in the list? Eliminating the pointer should make the issue of destruction pretty much moot.

Comment: Clarifying: The destructor looks good. We need a [mcve] and I recommend adding the text of any reported error message to the question along with it. And remove the code image. They don't do anything for you except attract downvotes.

Comment: Hi, I am guessing that the last piece of code you posted which you're calling an error, is where the debugger breaks when you're trying to run this application. And I am guessing that your program is crashing somewhere while it's freeing some memory. It is really difficult to know what's going on without an example. Could you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That will help us see what's wrong. Also what does the destructor of `Fronteira` look like?

Comment: @user4581301 Hey! Yeah I really need to use that Arestas* class. I think the problem is that in the list key[1] when I delete the Aresta* with [3,100] when I go for the list of key[2] and I try to delete the Aresta* [3,50] appears that as nothing there. But I don’t know how to work it out. Is there a way in C++ to know if a pointer as already deleted ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Using the class is a must. Do you need a pointer to the class? Library containers like `map` and `list` are at their best when they contain objects directly. They are almost always faster, too.

Comment: There is no easy way to know if a pointer has previously been deleted. It's up to the programmer to ensure that the allocation is not freed more than once. If you must use pointers, look into guaranteeing ownership with [Smart Pointers.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry, already edit it out. Thanks for the tip ! I did the whole project around the pointer because I can change it in multiple functions, I don’t know if it makes sense. But if there’s no way of resolving this way I ll need to work it out without using the pointer as you say!

Comment: @AdamZahran My ´Fronteira` destructor doesn't have nothing in it since none of the variables inside it are alocated dinamically. But I can provide the Fronteira Class aswell if you need. In the error doesn't give me any in the console, just when I run it with a debugger so that Error that I put in my question is when it breakpoints as you said.

Comment: [mcve] required to give more than general suggestions, and I've given al the good general suggestions I can think of. Make certain you've handled the Rule of Three correctly.

Comment: is `custo` a unique id?

Comment: Post your [MCVE] to continue.

Comment: Don't write the answer in the question.

Comment: *I was trying to delete the same `vertice*` in another `Aresta*`* `std::shared_ptr` might be the tool of choice here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry, didn't know I couldn't right it in the question ! Already edit it out.

Comment: It is @AdamZahran I already solved the problem thanks to all of you ! Thanks !

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for all the tips I'll pay more attention to the Rule of Three from now on!

Comment: My closevote is because the question is incomplete, specifically lacks a [mcve]. Get used to doing stuff like the MCVE. It's not for us; crafting a MCVE almost always helps you find the problem without any outside help. If you make a MCVE before you ask, odds are good you won't have to ask.

Comment: @user4581301 but why not do like you did before, and said like don't use images in code, or something instead of downvoting ? I think it helps more people than just put a document. It's more friendly you know ? I will make sure to make a MCVE before I ask my next question ! Thanks

Comment: Look up at comment 2. It asked for the MCVE as well suggesting you remove the image. Note how none of the answers really answered your questions outright. They mostly suggested places for you to look, because the question cannot be answered properly as written.

Comment: I totally understand that @user4581301 and I do understand the utility of MCVE, but I got my problem solved without that this time. Now I have to make sure I use MCVE. The problem is if you downvote me when it will be the next question ?

Comment: We're not downvoting you, at least I hope people aren't. We're downvoting the question. Good (complete and original) questions generally get upvoted. Marginal questions generally get left alone, bad questions get downvoted. Looks like this one got one downvote and two closevotes. That's not too bad, really. Some sink to -10 and are closed and deleted within a minute, but those are usually *Gimmie teh coedz!!!* questions or questions that are duplicated many times every day like, *Why does `++i + i++` not equal 3?*. You provided enough for good, guided guesswork and got an answer. That's a win.

Comment: @user4581301 see that couple of words made me want to make good questions using MCVE. Thanks dude !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have an issue with the ownership of your structures. You had these arestas several times in your lists, and it's undefined behavior to delete them several times, so you need to delete them just once.

Try something like this:

```
std::set<Arestas*> s;

for(const auto& p1: m)
{
    for(const auto& el: p1.second)
    {
        s.insert(el);
    }
}
```

So you create a set of all the elements you need to delete. And then you delete them (works also with unique pointers, a better solution actually).

```
for(auto p: s)
{
    delete p;
}
```

It seems that your Arestas may be unique, so the problem could lie in Arestas destructor if the `vertice` are shared and destroyed there.

Comment: How do you guarantee the uniqueness of Arestas pointers in that set? if two pointers point to the same object, they're not the same and the set will still take them in.

Comment: Yeah that `vertice` is the same in all the `Arestas*` like [3,100] and [3,50]. And that is the problem, I was wondering if I could delete all the vertices after I deleted my map. I don't know if I maked my self clear.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, after looking at my code the problem was on Arestas destructor.

Comment: In the example given there was no commonality between the lists.

Comment: Ok @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know what to say, how was it like your first question in stackoverflow ? Did you have someone like you in all of the comments saying that you did a bad question ? Even tough a lot of people got the answer right ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ahaa I see, the edges are unique. OK, that makes sense now.

Comment: @diogofalken No because I read the site's instructions before posting

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you only can `delete` objects previously created with `new` statement.

If so, in order to avoid multiple calls to delete, you could use a smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr<Aresta>`.

You could execute your code with Valgrind to get a more specific trace of this problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I am not sure if I can use this smart pointer because I am doing this project for my OOP class. And since I never learned it in class, I am not allowed to use it.

Comment: Are you creating `vertice` with new too?

Comment: Multiple frees are unlikely to be the problem since all the list elements across the map are unique. Possibilities include never dynamically allocating in the first place but we simply do not have enough information to know.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah sorry for the lack of information, but since is a school project I can't really publish all my code. But the problem was in the destructor of the `Aresta`. Thanks !

Comment: @diogofalken You need to have some way to understand when your objects are owned and when they're not owned. One possibility is to have a link count in the object. When you delete a link, decrement the link count. If the link count reaches zero, delete the object. This can be made elegant by having the link be an object whose constructor increments the count and destructor decrements it.

Comment: @diogofalken You're welcome. It might be overkill for your particular issue, but it's a good technique to know. A very important general concept is that you really need to think about who owns what objects and what is responsible for cleaning them up and how it will know when to do that.  If you haven't already, you'll soon learn to use things like `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` to make this easier in many cases.

Comment: I am not sure if I am going to learn about that type of pointers but I will learn for my self. Since it looks like it will make easier to use pointers ! Thanks @DavidSchwartz